# Why time.mktime returns different result on windows and linux for same input?

Tags: python-3.x

time.mktime behaves differently on windows and linux. 
For a datetime value '0001-01-01 00:00:00' , on windows it throws exception **"OverflowError: mktime argument out of range"** while on Linux it does not throw any exception and returns an incorrect (-ve) value.

**on windows -**

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse    
>>> dt = parse('0001-01-01 00:00:00')
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
>>> time.mktime(dt.timetuple())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: mktime argument out of range
```

**On Linux**

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse    
>>> dt = parse('0001-01-01 00:00:00')
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
>>> time.mktime(dt.timetuple())
-62135596800.0
```

any pointer as to why same function is behaving differently on windows and Linux is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying C libraries for `mktime` used by the Python implementations for Windows and Linux are different.

As the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.mktime) points out:

> The earliest date for which it (`mktime`) can generate a time is
>   platform-dependent.